# What RFC of JSON is implemented in ECMAScript 2015?

Tags: json, ecmascript-6, rfc

**My question**

What RFC (4627, 7158, 7159) of [JSON](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159) is implemented in [ECMAScript 2015](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/)?

I am asking because of a problem I ran into parsing a plain string with `JSON.parse()`.

**What I did**

`var parsed = JSON.parse("aCustomString")`

**Expected behaviour**

`parsed === "aCustomString"`

**Actual behaviour**

`SyntaxError: Unexpected token a in JSON at position 0`

Maybe I missunderstood the RFC, but it sounded that `"aCustomString"` is as valid as `{"key":"value"}`

Comment: `"aCustomString"` is a valid JSON string. But it also is a JS string literal for the string value `aCustomString`, and trying to parse that (which is what your code is doing) obviously fails. Try `JSON.parse('"aCustomString"')` or `JSON.parse("\"aCustomString\"")`

Comment: The [ES2015](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-json-object) spec states: _"Conforming implementations of `JSON.parse` and `JSON.stringify` support the exact interchange format described in the [ECMA-404](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-404.htm) specification"_. In the last paragraph of the [fifth page](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf) of the _ECMA-404_ spec it states _"**The JSON syntax specified by this specification and by RFC 8259 are intended to be identical."**_ (RFC 8259 was an update of RFC 4627)